# How do you show a loading screen while creating database?

Tags: android, database, multithreading

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        loadData();
        setContentView(R.layout.preload);

        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               setUpDB();
               setContentView(R.layout.main);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
```

So I want it to show the preload view while the database is setting up (setUpDB) and then switch to the main view when the setup is complete change to the main view. I had it almost working; showing the loader until about 80% and then crashing, but now I can't even get it to show the loader...  if I have setUpDB() in the thread it crashes, if I have it outside the thread it shows a blank screen until fully loaded. I can't remember the code I had before... any ideas?

Comment: what are you doing in setupDb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a Handler and call it to update your UI like this,

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

ProgressDialog pd=ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Please Wait...");
Handler handler =new Handler()
{
 public void handleMessage(Message msg)
{
 if(msg.what==0)
{
 pd.dismiss();
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
};   
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  loadData();
                   setUpDB();
                  handler.sendEmptyMEssage(0);
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        }
```

Comment: hmm... This goes into the main view before the database is fully loaded

Comment: Then instead of progress dialog you can show a splash screen or something.

Comment: Actually this works fine on my device but crashes on the emulator. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't give any error but crashes. I will try re-install the emulators should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this using assynctask..

```
         private class LoadAssync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> { // Assync task

    protected void onPreExecute() {

            ProgressDialog dialog=ProgressDialog.show(this,"","Loading");

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
         setUpDB();

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {


        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

to execute assynctask

```
LoadAssync mAsyync1;

mAsyync1 = new LoadAssync();
            mAsyync1.execute(null);
```

Comment: but how do you setContentView's within AsyncTask?

Comment: set the contentview in post execute

Answer (score 0):

```
    setUpDB();
    splashHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(STOP_SPLASH, STOP_SPLASH_DELAY);

private Handler splashHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
        case STOP_SPLASH:
                            progressbar.dismiss();  
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    HomeScreenActivity.class));
            finish();
            break;
        }
    };
};
```